# Fetching String, Id from Map - Illegal Assignment Id to Field / Object

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I'm writing some code which will insert the Id of a Target__c (custom object) record into a field called Target__c in the Master Detail field of a junction object TargetxOpp__c.

The Identifier fields contain a *key* which enables me to match an Opportunity record with a Target__c record.

When I try to fetch the Target__c record Id from a map, in this line

```
Target__c t1 = targets.get(opp.Identifier__c);
```

I get the following error message

> Illegal assignment from Id to Target__c

Since the error message doesn't state 'SObject:Target__c' I think my code's confusing the reference to the custom object Target__c with the custom field on the TargetxOpp__c object - Target__c.

I'm guessing that there's a way to avoid this *confusion* without renaming the field but I'm not sure how to?

Here's my code, to keep it short, I've left out the first part of the code which just creates a list of Opportunity's with a specific record type, to work with.

```
trigger NewOpportunityTarget on Opportunity (after insert) {

        Set<String> identifiers = new Set<String>();
        for(Opportunity o1 : oppIds){
            identifiers.add(o1.Identifier__c);
        }

        //create map of target records with an identifier that matches the Opportunity's
        map<String,Id> targets = new map <String,Id>();
        for(Target__c t: [SELECT Identifier__c, Id FROM Target__c
                           WHERE Identifier__c in :identifiers])
            targets.put(t.Identifier__c, t.Id);

        List<TargetxOpp__c> newLinks = new List<TargetxOpp__c>();
        for(Opportunity opp : oppIds){

            TargetxOpp__c j = new TargetxOpp__c();

            // fetch Id of Target record, based on Opportunity identifier
            Target__c t1 = targets.get(opp.Identifier__c);

            j.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
            j.Target__c = t1.Id;

            newLinks.add(j);
        }
        insert newLinks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are making is that you are trying to retrieve a Target__c object from a map that only contains Id's.

If you need the complete Target__c record instead of the Id, you need to put the Target__c record in the map (and not the Id). So like this:

```
map<String,Target__c> targets = new map <String,Target__c>();
for(Target__c t: [SELECT Identifier__c, Id FROM Target__c
                           WHERE Identifier__c in :identifiers])
    targets.put(t.Identifier__c, t);
```

Alternatively, if you only need the Id, then don't assign to a Target__c record but to an Id:

```
Id t1Id = targets.get(opp.Identifier__c);
```

and

```
j.Target__c = t1Id;
```

Comment: Apologies, I was too quick to comment, I figured out the cause of both issues.

Comment: ok, no problem :-)